# Image Upload using Rest API| Implementation approach

Tags: image, rest, azure-blob-storage

Our team is trying to build endpoints for our RESTful Public API to enable image upload on a digital whiteboard. Due to various reasons, including implementation on the core product, we have decided to make it a 3-step process:

1. getUploadURL (Azure Blob)
2. PUT image
3. Create thumbnail rendering image on the whiteboard

Here are the questions that we are struggling with and would be great to have your opinion on:

- Should we generate the Azure URL with finite time-to-live (TTL)? If yes, how much?
- What should we do if someone performs Steps 1 & 2 and never performs Step 3? Delete uploaded file and expire the URL?
- If a user performs all 3 steps, create thumbnail, save data, and set Azure URL TTL to never expire? Any other considerations that we are missing out?

Really appreciate guidance on this.

We tried to think of a single step process but that would require massive refactoring of the internal codebase.

Answer (score 0):

[novi_ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18629443/novi-ajax), Stack overflow is for more of programmatical problems but I found some info for you.

1. **A higher TTL reduces the perceived latency of a site and decreases the dependency on the authoritative name servers**. The lower the TTL, the sooner the cached record expires. This allows queries for the records to occur more frequently. You can refer some best practices [here](https://docs.rackspace.com/support/how-to/about-ttl-best-practices/). If you use CDN, you can choose to set no TTL on a file.  [Azure CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-manage-expiration-of-cloud-service-content) automatically applies a default TTL of **seven days**.  You are the best judge of setting the TTL based on usage.
2. If your end goal is create the thumbnails on whiteboard, its best to delete the uploaded file and expire the URL to save the space and cost. You can think some buffer time (for performing step 3) before you delete the things.
3. I think you have taken care all the things.